# Are unicode symbols supported in QGIS labels?

Tags: qgis, labeling, unicode

I want to use unicode symbols in a QGIS label - is this supported?
I.e. I have this expression for labelling a line:

```
case when xat(-1) - xat(0) > 0 then
  'GF ->' 
else
  '<- GF'
end
```

and want to replace the '->' and '<-' with the unicode characters representing left and right arrows.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Unicode in your expressions for any label. Just copy and paste your Unicode character, in any way you like, in your code:

[image]

And here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With QGIS 3.x we can use unicode symbols (aka Emojis) everywhere:

[image]

If we want to show colorful emojis in map canvas - like in the example above - we have to switch label rendering to always text:
[image]

Unfortunately, we loose all colors in map composer and when printing/exporting:
[image]

But it's definitely a nice way to display symbols in feature labels.

The complete list of emojis is here: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

To use the emojis in QGIS, we can copy the symbols directly from the `Browser` column (see link above). No need to enter any hex codes .