# Adding super/sub script in QGIS text annotation?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, annotation

How can I add a super/sub script in a QGIS text annotation? For example, 44.95 mi^2.

[image: example image with superscript 2]

Comment: Maybe you can do it via Unicode, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90076/are-unicode-symbols-supported-in-qgis-labels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @artwork21 suggested, you can do it via Unicode but I find it much easier to just write the text with super/sub scripts from a text editor such as Microsoft Word and copy/paste into the annotation:

[image: Microsoft Word]

[image: Annotation with superscript]