# How to design labels which look like a fraction (with a fraction line)?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to create labels like a fraction using data from two columns. I have tried to use:

```
"Field" || '\n' || '――' || '\n' || "Field2"
```

but it doesn't look good. How can I do it using other method?

Here I have added the picture[image]

Comment: Is it really a fraction? In which case maybe you need to present it as a percentage. If its one thing over another (like a blood pressure as 120/80) then maybe slashes like that? Typesetting fractions is probably beyond the labelling engine...

Comment: Data from one field must be under data from other field. And they must be separated by horizontal line.

Comment: A picture speaks a thousand words - got a sample image of how you want this to look - and maybe also what your attempt looks like and how it fails?

Comment: Please expand upon "... but it doesn't look good." What else are you trying to achieve? What's not working? You can set horizontal alignment to Center to make the 'fraction' look better.

Comment: I don't like that the line beetween data looks like "----" not solid.

Comment: You can try using a Unicode character for the fraction bar. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90076

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `\n—\n` separator (em-dash in the middle) and setting multiline height to 0.6 and multiline alignment to center (in the "Formatting" sub-tab).